# How to update urwid.Text widget dynamically?

Tags: python, urwid

I'm working on TUI spotify player with urwid library and can't figure out how to update text with the name of playing track every time track is changed.

I have 2 widgets on the screen. First with liked tracks and second with currently playing track. I know about function `currrent_playback` but I don't understand how to get information that user changed a song and correspondingly text with currently playing song should be changed.

I came up with this function, but still don't understand how can I call it every time user changes track:

```
def get_current_playing_track(sp):
    playback = sp.current_playback()
    if playback and playback['is_playing']:
        return f"{playback['item']['artists'][0]['name']} | {playback['item']['name']}"
    else:
        return 'Nothing is playing now...'
```

Function for creating "liked tracks widget"

```
# right_part of the screen
def liked_tracks_widget(liked_tracks, sp):
    right_part = urwid.Overlay(liked_tracks, urwid.SolidFill(u'\N{MEDIUM SHADE}'),
    align='right', width=('relative', 50),
    valign='top', height=('relative', 90),
    min_width=20, min_height=9)

    return right_part
```

Function for displaying "currently playing track widget"

```
# lower part of the screen
def playing_track_widget(sp, playing_track):

    text_object = urwid.Text(playing_track)
    text_filler = urwid.Filler(text_object, 'bottom')
    frame = urwid.Frame(text_filler, footer=None)

    return frame
```

Main function, where I run urwid loop:

```
# main function for TUI
def run_tui(tracks, sp):
    liked_tracks = urwid.Padding(convert_to_ListBox(u'Liked Tracks', tracks.values(), sp), left=2, right=2)

    # updated state of currently playing track
    playing_track = get_current_playing_track(sp)

    # widget with liked tracks
    right_part = liked_tracks_widget(liked_tracks, sp)

    # widget with currently playing track
    lower_part = playing_track_widget(sp, playing_track)

    columns = urwid.Columns([
        ('weight', 1, lower_part),
        ('weight', 1, right_part)
        ], dividechars=1)

    main_loop = urwid.MainLoop(columns, unhandled_input=unhandled_input)

    main_loop.run()
```